# How do I upgrade to the latest ruby in Ubuntu 16.04 properly?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, ruby

I am trying to upgrade Ruby to the latest in Ubuntu 16.04.  I can't use virtual environment for ruby because I need to use latest version of Ruby inside python virtual env.  So I decided to upgrade the system default Ruby (current version is 2.3.1)

I was able to install 2.7.1 via snap:

```
$ sudo snap install ruby --classic
ruby 2.7.1 from Ruby core team (rubylang✓) installed
```

But when I check the version, it still show 2.3.1

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

How do I upgrade the ruby version properly from here?

```
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

$ whereis ruby
ruby: /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.3 /usr/lib/ruby /snap/bin/ruby.gem
/snap/bin/ruby.bundle /snap/bin/ruby.env /snap/bin/ruby.irb 
/snap/bin/ruby.rake /snap/bin/ruby.rdoc /snap/bin/ruby.ri 
/snap/bin/ruby /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz

$ /snap/bin/ruby -v
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install from a source (ref: https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04)

```
wget http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.7/ruby-2.7.1.tar.gz
tar -xzvf ruby-2.7.1.tar.gz
cd ruby-2.7.1/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

then reopen terminal

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-linux]
```